# Why is Klein's quartic curve not hyperelliptic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be Klein's quartic curve given by $x^3y + y^3z+z^3x=0$ in $\mathbf{P}^2$. It is isomorphic to $X(7)$.

How do I easily show that $X$ is **not** hyperelliptic?

I can see that $X$ is of genus $3$ and has gonality $\leq 3$ (consider the projection). I'm trying to prove that it has gonality $3$.

More generally, what is a computationally feasible way to check if a curve is **not** hyperelliptic?

Note that I'm not really asking for a criterion. For example, to check if a variety is  normal you could try to show that it is regular (which is easier to me).

Is the obvious morphism $X\to \mathbf{P}^1$ of degree $3$ Galois? That is, do we have that $X$ is a cyclic cover of degree $3$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a smooth curve $X$ of genus $g\geq 3$ (like the Klein quartic, which has genus $g=3$ as you remarked), the criterion you want is ([Miranda](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebraic_curves_and_Riemann_surfaces.html?id=qjg6GOQaHNEC&redir_esc=y) ,  Chap.VII, Prop. 2.1):

$X$ is *not* hyperelliptic $\iff$ the canonical map $X\to \mathbb P^{g-1}$ *is* an embedding.

Conclude by remembering  that if $X\subset \mathbb P^{g-1} $ is already embedded   as a curve of of degree $2g-2$ (but  not included in a hyperplane), then the canonical map is an embedding: [Griffiths-Harris](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Sny48qKdW40C&printsec=frontcover&dq=griffiths+harris&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=nht8T9OfNce78gPoxJjSDQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=griffiths%20harris&f=false), page 247.