# Example of a curve with this property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading [Fulton's book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and he defines the linear series $g_n^r$:

[image]

So a curve $C$ is trigonal if it has a divisor which has a linear system $g_3^1$. I'm looking for a simple example of a trigonal curve.

I really need help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A smooth projective curve $C$  is said to be trigonal if there exists a ramified covering $C\to \mathbb P^1$ of degree $3$ but no such ramified covering  of degree $2$.
The first condition means that $C$ has a linear system of the form $g^1_3$ and the second  means that $C$ is not hyperelliptic (nor rational, nor elliptic).

The simplest example of a trigonal curve is a smooth quartic in $C\subset\mathbb P^2$, for example (in characteristic $\neq2$) the curve $x^4+y^4+z^4=0$ .
The projection of $C$ from some point $p\in  C$ onto an arbitrary line $L\subset \mathbb P^2$ not containing $p$ immediately furnishes the required $3:1$ covering from $C$ to $L\cong \mathbb P^1$.
That  $C$ is not hyperelliptic  [has already been discussed   on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127938/3217).

Comment: I didn't study about ramidied coverings yet. I'm trying this construction: Given a regular map $\varphi:C\to \mathbb P^n,P\mapsto \mathbb (f_0(P):f_1(P):\ldots:f_n(P))$, we can associate a linear system $|\varphi|$ in the following manner: let the divisor $D=-\min div(f_i)$ and $V$ be the vector space of every linear combination of the functions $f_i$. Thus we define $|\varphi|=\{div(g)+D\mid g\in V\}$. If $\varphi:C\to \mathbb P^1$, where $\varphi=(f_1,f_2)$ and $f_1=y/x$ and $f_2=x^2/y^2$, then $D=P_1+2P_2$ and $\deg(D)=3$. So this $C$ is a trigonal curve, right?